# How to get sum of json array

Tags: javascript, json

So, I am fetching values from a database and then i am returning/using them in JSON/javascript as an array for example as shown here

[image: Alert with data used]

The problem is that I want the sum of the array elements.
I used this code:

```js
var obj1 = JSON.parse(data);
var mar = obj1.march;
var quantite = obj1.quant;
const sum = quantite.reduce((result,number)=> result+number);

console.log(sum);
```

And here is what I got in the console

[image: Value in the the console]

I am totally new into JSON and javascript, so, any tips/help would be great for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in the array are strings and so, when you use the `+` operator it concatenates them. You want to parse them first like this:

```
const sum = quantite.reduce((result,number)=> parseInt(result) + parseInt(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you data contains strings, not int.
You can improve your reduce function:

```js
quantite.reduce((result,number) => parseInt(result)+parseInt(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the start value of reduce() and make sure `number` isn't a string when adding it

```
quantite.reduce((res,num)=> (res + Number(number)),0);
                                 // start value   ^^^
```